# Storing remainder and quotient in the same register in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

I have two unsigned 6-bit values that I divided. I am trying to store the quotient in the 6 least significant bits of `$v0` and then store the remainder in the next 6 bits of `$v0`. I know that `mfhi` and `mflo` are used to access the quotient and remainder, but they are 32 bits each. My initial thought was to:

1. Isolate the 6-bits of each that are needed
2. Shift the quotient over 6 bits
3. Xor them together
4. Assign the result to `$v0`

Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: _"Is there an easier way to do this?"_ Not really. Your step-by-step doesn't seem to match your description though. If the quotient should go into the 6 least significant bits, then it would seem logical to me to shift the remainder rather than the quotient.

Comment: XOR them together?  I don't think that's what you want.  You might want to `OR` them together once you have them in the right positions.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer: In this case XOR would have the same effect. There's one value in b[5:0] of one register, and another value in b[11:6] of another register. All other bits in both registers are zero (_"Isolate the 6-bits of each that are needed"_).